# onBackPressed not working properly

Tags: android

I want to return back to MainActivity on clicking back button from each fragment and destroy Activity after returning back to the MainActivity.
I have tried something but it is continuously calling the fragment but not destroying it.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    startActivity(new Intent(this,MainActivity.class));
    finish();
}
```

Comment: @nawinkhatiwada delete the answer

Comment: oops sorry the question was posted as answer

Comment: Where are you placing this code? In addition, where is it you're trying to go back from...is it another `Activity` class, or is it from a `Fragment` attached to the `Activity` where you override this method? **Edit:** also, what do you  mean by "continuously calling the fragment but not destroying it" - the above method will start an `Activity`, not a `Fragment`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do something like this in your MainActivity:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
   Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frameLayout);
     if (fragment instanceof YourFragment || fragment instanceof YourOtherFragment) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frameLayout, new MainScreenFragment()).commit();
        }else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try this way. @nawinkhitiwada

Comment: for more information i have extended AppCompatActivity in MainActivity

Comment: Yes, It will work with AppCompatActivity. Can you explain with code more? @navin

Comment: the app directly closes on clicking back button its not working

Comment: but the title of the fragment is not displayed correctly in the actionBar do u have any idea #priyanka

Comment: In your activity, where you are adding fragment, call setTitle("Your Title");

Comment: You should mark the answer Right. If it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the Mainactivity

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
            this.finish();
        } else {
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        }
    }
```